# Alert(Level: Fatal, Description: Decode Error) - Forwarding Proxy

Tags: c, sockets, ssl, https, proxy

I'm trying to make a forwarding proxy but I keep getting an

```
Alert(Level: Fatal, Description: Decode Error)
```

after the Client sends...

```
Client Key Exchange, Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message
```

[image]

[image]

> Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?
>
> I can't seem to get a grasp on what the error even means. Does it mean
>   the initial encrypted packet by the client fails to be decrypted by
>   the server? If so, then why?

UPDATE 1

I just was looking at the packets and I noticed a significant difference between using my proxy, and not using the proxy.

The DFE key isn't being interpereted with my proxy.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You didn't say it clearly, are you coding a proxy ? Once the connection is established on the two parts after the CONNECT success, the proxy is supposed to become "invisible" by forwarding each byte from one part to another, is this what you coded ? Are you sure those 3 bytes are bytes of nothing and not the 3 first bytes of an SSL handshake (hexa : 16 03 01 for a TLS 1.2) ? Could we see those bytes in their real hexa value ?

Comment: @EugèneAdell I will check this now.

Comment: @EugèneAdell Dude you were right! Thank you! I must not be forwarding something correctly.

Comment: You're wellcome. You still can come back to answer your own question and get some reputation points ;)

Comment: @EugèneAdell I'm still running into a problem. When I forward those three bytes to the destination. I get no response :( .

Comment: The client hello is much more than 3 bytes, and forwarding only 3 bytes cannot work. What are these 3 bytes, can you check their value than we are sure they are the beginning of an handshake (see above the hexa values)

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23617741/8074683) may help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

You're not forwarding the exact amount of data that the proxy is supposed to forward.

But I see you're going further now than at the beginning of your question (good !)

You are implementing a proxy which forwards every single byte which it receives, in both ways, and either it sends too much to the server, or not enough. Check your code again for any conditions when you stop reading the input data to forward, be sure you're forwarding exactly everything. Nothing more, nothing less.

RFC 5246, about Decode Error :

> decode_error
>         A message could not be decoded because some field was out of the
>         specified range or the length of the message was incorrect.  This
>         message is always fatal and should never be observed in
>         communication between proper implementations (except when messages
>         were corrupted in the network).

Comment: I just triple checked all my packet lengths and they are correct! I'm so confused. Please see my update to the question though :) .

Comment: At which place are you taking the network capture ? You can make a tcpdump filter to capture on your proxy, both incoming and outgoing traffic, this will tell us if it is really forwarding without any alteration.  Wireshark is probably unable to display the DHE key while its length is correct, I will say the packet has been altered and Wireshark can't decode it correctly (we often see that). You can see in the Packet Bytes pane ( https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChUsePacketBytesPaneSection.html ) but a bit hard for newbies. Save capture as K12 text format, copy it here.

Comment: @Roecrew did you give up or solve your problem ? There's one bounty lost unfortunately.